Why won't lazy.nvim update itself?
I'm trying to update to the latest lazy version for quite some time, but lazy refuses to and stays on the same version.


It would be better to ask on https://vi.stackexchange.com instead.

I had the same problem... it was because lazy was installed in a different folder than the plugins.
check your lazy.lua file. it should look like this
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath('data') ... '/lazy/lazy.nvim'.
...

look at the last part, it should be /lazy/lazy.nvim in my case I followed a tutorial that said /lua/lazy.nvim.
